# background image scrolling, with click controls

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick, scrollto

on a webpage, I have a div named posts, with inside this divs several divs named post, all with a background image.
I managed to write a code to scroll the background images when scrolling the scrollbar, body scrolling.
it works perfectly.

here is my html :

```
<div id="posts" class="hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <div class="post format_L photo" style="background-image:url(http://www.mmdwc.com/wp-content/uploads/1210-807-2.jpg)" alt="mmm artisanal" id="1"></div>
    <div class="post format_L photo" style="background-image:url(http://www.mmdwc.com/wp-content/uploads/1210-807-3.jpg)" alt="mmm artisanal" id="2"></div>
    <div class="post format_L photo" style="background-image:url(http://www.mmdwc.com/wp-content/uploads/1210-807.jpg)" alt="mmm artisanal" id="3"></div>
</div>
```

my CSS :

```
#posts {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.post {
    background-size: auto 80%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and my jquery :

```
/* BACKGROUND SCROLL*/
    var lastpost = $(".post").last().offset().top
    var page = 1
    var loading = false

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if (loading) return;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > lastpost - window.innerHeight*1.5) {

            loading = true
            var $div = $("<div>")
            $div.load("/page/" + (++page) + " .post", function(){

                $("#posts").append($div.find(".post"))
                lastpost = $(".post").last().offset().top
                loading = false

            });

        }
    });
```

now I'm trying to add 2 divs, one named arrow_down, and the other arrow_up, when clicking on arrow_down, body scroll to the next div, and when clicking on arrow_up, we scroll to the previous div.

here is my html :

```
<div class="controls">
    <div class="arrow_down">Down</div>
    <div class="arrow_up">Up</div>
</div>
```

my CSS :

```
.controls {
    position : fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

and my jquery :

```
function scrollToPosition(element) {
    if (element !== undefined) {
        $("body, html").scrollTo(element, 800, {
            margin: true
        });
    }
}

    //Create an Array of posts
    var posts = $('.post');
    var position = 0; //Start Position
    var next = $('.arrow_down');
    var prev = $('.arrow_up');


    next.click(function(evt) {
        //Scroll to next position
        scrollToPosition(posts[position += 1]);
        if (position === posts.length - 1) {
        }
    });

    prev.click(function(evt) {
        //Scroll to prev position    
        scrollToPosition(posts[position -= 1]);
        if (position === 0) {
        }
    });
```

it works fine also.

But my problem, is that after manually scrolling the page to go to the next image, if I click on arrow_down, the body scrolls to the next image of the image that was viewed (like the image was viewed was memorized). so the 2 arrow controls are not synchronized with my manual scroll.

In fact, I guess I would need to check which post divs is inview, and when cliking on arrow_down, scrolling to the next post. I don't know if you understand what I mean ?

**here is a good way to understand :
manually scroll to image 3 (with mouse, not by clicking), and then click on arrow down.logically you are supposed to go to the 4th image... BUT it will scroll to the image 2, because the manual scroll is not detected, and you'are supposed to start from image 1, so Image 1 + 1 = image 2**

I am able to add unique Id to each post divs, I think it's a good start of doing it, but I'm stucked now...

here is a jsfiddle to see it in action :

http://jsfiddle.net/0hd2k2jf/6/

hope someone can help me with this, maybe there's another way of doin it... but I definitly need to keep the background images slideshow.

Another way of doin it will be to add the two buttons, arrow_up and arrow_down. and when clicking on it, it will scroll my window, the same way as the default scrollbar, just like the scrollbar from the old browsers. arrow_up and arrow_down would be synchronized with my scrollbar. that would be in fact the perfect solution, but I can't find any ressource or way of doin it. maybe somebody can help with this to ?

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working fine. Couldn't understand the exact problem.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, I've updtaded my jsfiddle with a 4th image. manually scroll to image 3 (with mouse, not by clicking), and then click on arrow down.logically you are supposed to go to the 4th image... BUT it will scroll to the image 2, because the manual scroll is not detected, and you'are supposed to start from image 1, so Image 1 + 1 = image 2. you see what I mean ? http://jsfiddle.net/0hd2k2jf/6/

Comment: Sorry, couldn't see any problem.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal please take a look at my comment and the new jsfiddle.

Comment: @vel, please take a look at my comment and the new jsfiddle.

Comment: @mmdwc Im checking your code

Comment: @vel thanks ! let me know if you don't understand

Comment: I understood your problem. The problem is increment of position value

Comment: @vel, yes that's it... I can't think of a solution... do you ? what do you think of the seconde position ? "dd the two buttons, arrow_up and arrow_down. and when clicking on it, it will scroll my window, the same way as the default scrollbar, just like the scrollbar from the old browsers. arrow_up and arrow_down would be synchronized with my scrollbar"

Comment: Yes @mmdwc Im looking solution. let me check..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0hd2k2jf/8/ is this what you are looking for

Comment: Yes. @mmdwc i think you got the solution..

Comment: @NithishThomas ! wahou ! great ! exactly what I was looking for ! I now need to understand your code, thank you both for your help !

Comment: @NithishThomas, You can answer to my question so I can vote !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out the current div the user is looking at so that you can use the up and down buttons.

```
var post_size=$(".post").height() #is the height of a single post
```

on the up and down button clicks you need to divide the current scroll position with the post_size to get the post which the user is looking at assuming all the post are of same size.

```
next.click(function(evt) {
    console.info($(document).scrollTop());
    console.info(post_size);

    var currentPage=Math.round($(document).scrollTop()/post_size); //get the current post the user is looking at

    console.info("next "+currentPage);
    //Scroll to next position
    if (currentPage === posts.length - 1) {
        console.info('at the end');
    }else{
        scrollToPosition(posts[currentPage+1]);
    }

});
```

Rest i used the same code as yours to scroll to the correct post. scrollTo was not working on my browser so updated it with something that worked for me feel free to change it.

```js
/* BACKGROUND SCROLL*/
var lastpost = $(".post").last().offset().top
var page = 1
var loading = false
var scrolling =false
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if (loading) return;

  
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > lastpost - window.innerHeight * 1.5) {

    loading = true
    var $div = $("<div>")
    $div.load("/page/" + (++page) + " .post", function() {

      $("#posts").append($div.find(".post"))
      lastpost = $(".post").last().offset().top
      loading = false

    });

  }
});

/* ARROW CONTROLS */

function scrollToPosition(element) {
  if (element !== undefined) {
    $('html, body').finish();
    scrolling=true;
    console.info('scrolling to ' + $(element).offset().top);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(element).offset().top
    }, 2000,function(){scrolling=false;});
  }
}

//Create an Array of posts
var posts = $('.post');
var position = 0; //Start Position
var next = $('.arrow_down');
var prev = $('.arrow_up');

//Better performance to use Id selectors than class selectors
next.click(function(evt) {
  var post_size = $(".post").height();
  console.info($(document).scrollTop());
  console.info(post_size);

  var currentPage = Math.round($(document).scrollTop() / post_size);

  console.info("next " + currentPage);
  //Scroll to next position
  if (currentPage === posts.length - 1) {
    console.info('at the end');
  } else {
    scrollToPosition(posts[currentPage + 1]);
  }

});

prev.click(function(evt) {
  
  var post_size = $(".post").height();
  console.info($(document).scrollTop());
  console.info(post_size);

  var currentPage = Math.round($(document).scrollTop() / post_size);
  console.info('prev ' + currentPage);
  //Scroll to prev position    
  if (currentPage === 0) {} else {
    scrollToPosition(posts[currentPage - 1]);
  }
});
```

```css
#posts {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.post {
  background-size: auto 80%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.controls {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <div class="arrow_up">Up</div>
  <div class="arrow_down">Down</div>
</div>


<div id="posts" class="hidden-md hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <div class="post format_L photo" style="background-image:url(http://images.akamai.steamusercontent.com/ugc/547511114426230968/6E44158F7B8B19739ABF834A1C524A1D6BBCD687/)" alt="mmm artisanal" id="1"></div>
  <div class="post format_L photo" style="background-image:url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AgPay1JWsEQ/UpDLUnqCTgI/AAAAAAAAAdQ/VrgFrHCgGbw/s1600/512px-Number_2_in_light_blue_rounded_square.svg.png)" alt="mmm artisanal" id="2"></div>
  <div class="post format_L photo" style="background-image:url(http://lavoiedesreves.olympe.in/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/reve-chiffre-3.jpg)" alt="mmm artisanal" id="3"></div>
  <div class="post format_L photo" style="background-image:url(http://meganunchained.weebly.com/uploads/2/4/2/3/24232185/560060_orig.png)" alt="mmm artisanal" id="4"></div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following JS to the window scroll event:

```
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var postHeight = $('#posts').height();
    position = parseInt((scrollTop + (postHeight/2)) / postHeight);
```

Basically we get the position we're on each time you scroll the window. If you are more than half way down one of the posts it will scroll you to the next one; and vice versa for going up.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7x0y0q2/

You might want to change your prev function to only decrement the position if it's greater than 0:

```
prev.click(function(evt) {
    //Scroll to prev position    
    if(position > 0){
        position -= 1;
    }
    scrollToPosition(posts[position]);
    if (position === 0) {
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q7x0y0q2/1/